# How to load data from oracle database using .dsn? (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oracle11g, database-connection, connection-string

I'm trying to test if the connection from my utility to oracle DB is working by using .dsn . I've searched from many forums but to no avail . Here is my code:

```
    Dim filedsn As String = "C:\my_dsn.dsn"
    Dim uid As String = "id123"
    Dim pwd As String = "1234"

    Dim cn As OdbcConnection
    cn = New OdbcConnection("Driver=Oracle in OraClient11g_home2;Provider=msdaora;dsn=" & filedsn & ";uid=" & uid & ";pwd=" & pwd & ";")
    Dim mystring As String = "Select * from DD_CADS1.PDTABLE_12_1001"
    Dim cmd As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand(mystring)
    cn.Open()
    MsgBox("Connected")
    cn.Close()
```

But these error appears..

```
ERROR [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

ERROR [IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed
ERROR [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

Can you tell me what's the problem with my codes? Is there any other way to connect to oracle database through .dsn using VB.net?  I'm currently using ** Oracle 11g**.

Comment: I have never seen a dsn referenced as a file.  It is normally configured with the  ODBC Admin panel

Comment: You can do it in a file without any problem. Can be usefull is stored on a common place at a network share or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem in your code is that you use ODBC to connect to Oracle. You should use ODP.NET, which is even recommended by Microsoft. What you doing is there [most likely] for backwards compatibility and not to write the new stuff.

Here your problem is in connection string, which should look like this

```
 "DSN=oracledsn;UID=myUID;PWD=myPWD;Integrated Security=no;"
```

And you don't need `command` just to test connection

```
using cn= New OdbcConnection(".....")

    cn.Open() 
    if cn.State = ConnState.Open Then MessageBox.Show(...)
end using
```

When you use `using` it will take care of closing and disposing of connection.